# Why is there an error when getting an item from a ListView in an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, hashmap, android-arrayadapter

I created an ArrayAdapter for a ListView, and defined the TextView text of the element with the value "msg" of the ArrayList<HashMap<Object, Object>, up to that point all right, but when I create another element, the first element changes the text to the new "msg" value, does anyone know the error? (Text from Portuguese to English, sorry if the translation is wrong)

*Class ListViewAdapter*

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<Object,Object>> items;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<Object,Object>> items)
            {
                super(context, R.xml.chat, items);

                this.items = items;
            }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                if (view == null)
                    {
                        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.xml.chat, parent, false);
                    }

                TextView text_name = view.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
                TextView text_message = view.findViewById(R.id.text_message);

                text_message.setText(items.get(position).get("msg").toString());

                return view;
                
            }
            
    }
```

*MainAcrivity:*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
        public static ListView list_chat;
        public static EditText edit_message;
        public static Button button_send;

        public static ArrayList<HashMap<Object,Object>> list_map = new ArrayList<>();
        public static HashMap<Object,Object> user_map;
        public static HashMap<Object,Object> chat_map;
        public static HashMap<Object,Object> send_map;

        public static LayoutInflater inflaterChat;
        public static String BUILD;

        public static Texture texture;
        public static ListViewAdapter chatAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);


                list_chat = findViewById(R.id.list_chat);
                edit_message = findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
                button_send = findViewById(R.id.button_send);

                BUILD = Build.ID.replace(".", "");

                chatAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list_map);

                list_chat.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

                button_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    chat_map = new HashMap<>();

                                    chat_map.put("msg", edit_message.getText());

                                    list_map.add(chat_map);

                                    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                        });
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the error, I put "getText ()" in a HashMap value, and when the ListView was updated, instead of getting a value already defined, it executed the getText () command again Ex: Set String to " .getText ()" instead of "HashMap " My solution was to get the text in a String and then set the value of the HashMap with that String

```
  HashMap<Object,Object> chat_map = new HashMap<>();
  String message = String.valueOf(edit_message.getText());

  chat_map.put("msg", message);

  list_chat_map.add(chat_map);
```